# Error al mostrar una imagen Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

Hola comunidad espero estén teniendo un buen día. Disculpen la molestia, lo que pasa es que soy nuevo en el desarrollo con `Flutter` y estoy intentando desplegar una imagen pero no la muestra y no para de lanzarme un warning que dice que no es posible mostrar la imagen, tengo entendido que debo crear mi directorio de `assets` el cual ya está y lo debo agregar al archivo `pubspec.yaml` el cual ya lo hice y lo tengo de la siguiente manera:

```
uses-material-design: true
assets:
  - lib/assets/
```

y mando a llamar la imagen de esta forma:

```
Image.asset('logo.png')
```

Justamente mi directorio está en la ruta especificada de arriba y mi imagen ahí dentro con ese nombre pero no deja de aparecerme el error que no la puede mostrar. Si pueden ayudarme les estaré muy agradecido.

De antemano muchas gracias les deseo lo mejor y que tengan un excelente día. Bendiciones a todos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

es necesario que uses la ruta completa al momento de mostrar la imagen, así :

```
Image.asset("lib/assets/logo.png")
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, funcionó excelente, de ante mano te agradezco la ayuda, juro que lo intenté muchas veces y no funcionó, justo acabo de correr la app con esta solución y funcionó, muchas gracias

Comment: No hay problema :),  puedes declarar las imágenes con la ruta exacta en el pubspec.yaml o también puedes poner directorios como lo estás haciendo, pero siempre tienes que poner la ruta completa a la hora de usar la imagen :)

Comment: Genial, entonces seguiré probando, muchas gracias

Answer (score -2):

La forma correcta sería definiendo el recurso o el directorio que contiene los recursos dentro de tu archivo `yaml`, por ejemplo:

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - lib/assets/
    - lib/assets/logo.png
```

si dentro de `lib/assets` contienes la imagen `logo.png` , se realizaría de esta forma definiendo la ruta completa de la imagen:

```
 image: AssetImage('lib/assets/logo.png'),
```

o de la forma en que lo deseas realizar:

```
 new Image.asset('lib/assets/logo.png')
```

Revisa los documentos:

[Flutter: cargando imagenes (inglés)](https://flutter.io/assets-and-images/#loading-images-1)

[Clase AssetImage (inglés)](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/painting/AssetImage-class.html)